# How do I make my question non-personal?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

So I [asked this](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/42805/can-you-get-pregnant-from-having-sex-in-a-hot-tub-after-sitting-in-it-for-a-whil) because I've seen a funny youtube video which talked about such a situation, and couldn't google up anything concrete about it. The question remains − how does the heat affect sperm and why it's not a working contraception method.

I've asked questions like this before which may seem like I was trying to be funny, but I wasn't, and they got closed as "personal problems", which I think is a way for the community to say it's too anecdotal to look at seriously. They are not *too anecdotal* as apparently there are many questions like the one I'm posting about out there without a proper explanation. But I just want to know how I can make this one open for answers again.

Comment: Why do you feel the need to ask "funny" questions here? There are other places on the internet for such questions, like reddit's askscience forum.

Comment: That's the point − they're not "funny" to me, but apparently the rest think they are, and that I'm joking and laughing or whatever, but actually they're pretty legit questions, which most don't bother looking at. It's pretty immature coming from scientists in my opinion. The fact that there isn't any such question out there on the internet with explanation about why it won't work makes it perfectly valid on SE. I'd like to ask the users here to edit my question however you like to make it seem more attractive for possible answers, since apparently I can't.

Answer (score 1):

I would argue that these questions are off topic because "Biology Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for biology researchers, academics, and students". It's not a place to ask any random, trivial question that pops into your head after watching a youtube video.